# Chrome constantly claims that it didn't shut down correctly

Tags: google-chrome, shutdown, restore, session-restore

For past month or so, from time to time (every 2-3 days) when starting up Google Chrome I see constant claims that it didn't shut down correctly.

[image]

This seems to be a false claim, because:

- I always close Chrome with "x" button and always shut down the computer in the standard way.
- Every time I click on `Restore` Chrome opens my two startup pages and isn't actually restoring anything.

Where can I find some details about this behavior. Is it fixable? Can I do something to prevent or disable displaying this false warning?

I have recently upgraded my computer from Windows 7 Professional to Windows 10 Pro, but this should have no influence on reported problem, because I've seen this message before the upgrade, on Windows 7 as well.