# Chrome constantly claims that TortoiseSVN prevents it from working correctly

Tags: google-chrome, svn, compatibility, tortoise-svn

As a continuity to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1357121/156554). When ever Chrome claims that it didn't shut down correctly:

[image]

it also displays a separate tab, in which it claims that TortoiseSVN prevents it from working correctly:

[image]

I have the newest version of both TortoiseSVN and Google Chrome and while searching Internet I have found no evidence that these two applications cannot work together or causes each other any compatibility issues.

I've been using TortoiseSVN and Chrome on the same computers (at least 2-3) for past 5-6 years and I have never encountered any problems. Moreover, I wasn't even aware that TortoiseSVN needs Google Chrome for anything.

But, I did see these compatibility warning previously (i.e. while using Windows 7 -- I have upgraded to Windows 10 Pro recently -- and while using older version of TortoiseSVN and Chrome).

Based on above, I assume that this is a false claim from Chrome side.

Where can I find some details about this behaviour. It is fixable? Can I do something to prevent or disable displaying this false warning?

Answer (score 4):

I [have posted](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/2h11s3fksI4/LyEhgIFeBgAJ) the very same question to TortoiseSVN discussion board and I have received [a very detailed response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/2h11s3fksI4/nJZI4kdHCAAJ) from program's author itself.

In [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/2h11s3fksI4/nJZI4kdHCAAJ) there is a suggestion that what can be causing this problem and a possible solution:

> Try the TSVN settings dialog->icon overlays, check the box "Show overlays and context menu only in explorer". This will prevent Chrome from loading the TSVN shell extension.

However, as explained in [following answer by me](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/2h11s3fksI4/8E5PB650CAAJ), this is 99,99% bug inside current version of Google Chrome that has nothing to do TortoiseSVN.

It seems that problem with reporting TortoiseSVN as an incompatible with Google Chrome only appears as a next, after showing [incorrect "Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly" error](https://superuser.com/q/697618/156554). When browser is launched correctly and you manually go to *Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up > Update or remove incompatible applications* then you can clearly see that there are no problem and

> Done! No incompatible applications found

message appears.